# Updating complication's style on user preference change

Tags: wear-os, watch-face-api, watchface, android-wear-complication

I'm working on a Wear OS watchface using Jetpack WatchFace library and `ComplicationSlotsManager` to render complications. I'm looking into [WatchFaceKotlin Wear samples](https://github.com/android/wear-os-samples/blob/main/WatchFaceKotlin) for inspiration. I want to be able to change how the complications look like according to user's actions. Let's say user can chose a color style and complications will recolor accordingly.

This is also the case for the sample and it somehow works by rewriting complication slot renderer with new `ComplicationDrawable` each time there is a change. [This](https://github.com/android/wear-os-samples/blob/main/WatchFaceKotlin/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/wearable/alpha/AnalogWatchCanvasRenderer.kt#L209) is the code. Honestly I don't like this approach with casting and hoping that the type is right (which of course is, just it seems more like a workaround than a proper way to do it).

So I wonder, is there a better way to update complication slot renderer on user change? There is some invalidation mechanism on `ComplicationDrawable` (and `WatchFaceService`) but this is ultimately `internal` and not exactly what I'm looking for.

Since `ComplicationSlotsManager` is using factory (`CanvasComplicationFactory`) to create drawable I would expect this can be called every time it is needed but from what I can see in the source code this is just called once with lazy delegate, nothing more... Is it really it?